# Copied a bunch of files from windows to ubuntu server and now all the files are showing modified in git with ^M

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, line-endings, git-config

Transferred over 50k files from my windows box to my ubuntu server and now git diff is showing all my files are modified with ^M at the line endings.

I tried changing the auto.crlf to true in the command line and it doesn't work.

And no I can't recopy this over again as I don't have access to the windows box anymore.

I've constantly run into this and I never found a **simple way to fix this**.

Isn't there a simple option in the command line git to just ignore these ^M line endings? I don't want to go through to having to  make a script and reprocess all 50k files just to remove the ^M line endings.

Comment: It shouldn't be `auto.crlf` but `core.autocrlf` as explained in `man git-config`.

Answer (score 1):

auto crlf defines what happens during checkin and checkout.
If the files are already changed, then you may need to use a script after all.   If you have the dos2unix utility available you could just run that and specify all the files.

In the meantime, make sure you have the auto crlf  conversion setup the way you want it so this doesn't come up again.